# NSCountedSet in an if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscountedset

I am trying to `NSLog` the count of the number of @"1" inside of each label on my `ViewController`. I created 3 labels on the `storyboard`, then hooked up the `IBOutlet`. I added each of these labels into an `NSMutableArray` and alloc initWithObjects. I manually set the text of each label to be 1, 2, and 3.

Now to my issue.

I want to use a `NScountedSet` to count the number of 1's inside the array of labels. If the condition is met then NSLog some text.

I created a simple version of the code to highlight the issue.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *l1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *l2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *l3;



@property NSMutableArray *dice;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.l1.text isEqualToString:@"1"];
[self.l2.text isEqualToString:@"2"];
[self.l3.text isEqualToString:@"3"];


self.dice = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: self.l1, self.l2,  
self.l3, nil];




NSCountedSet *setOfNumbers = [NSCountedSet setWithObject:self.dice];


if ([setOfNumbers countForObject: @"1"  == 1]) {
    NSLog(@"Count of 1 in array is %lu", (unsigned long) [setOfNumbers  
countForObject:@"1"] );
}
```

I get 3 warnings...two yellow and 1 red.
My teachers told me this wont work and there are other ways to do it. And I have done it the other way. I am just really confused as to why this does not work. I'm only in week 2 of my class.

Can somebody explain why this doesn't work and how I could make it work?
Thank you

Comment: BTW - when you post a question about code issues, point out which lines are giving you an issue and post the actual error/warning messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues, obviously.

1. The lines like `[self.l1.text isEqualToString:@"1"];` don't do anything. You compare the label's text but don't check the result of the test.
2. You add the labels instead of the labels' text to the `self.dice` array.
3. You have a syntax error on the `if` line.
4. You create the counted set with the array instead of the objects in the array.
5. Store the count from the counted set in a variable so you don't calculate the count twice.

Here's some fixed code:

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dice = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.l1.text, self.l2.text, self.l3.text, nil];

    NSCountedSet *setOfNumbers = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:self.dice];

    NSUInteger count = [setOfNumbers countForObject: @"1"];
    if (count == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Count of 1 in array is %lu", (unsigned long)count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i realize my mistakes now!